# angular lazyload pages with same start path

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-lazyloading

I have a pretty big project and in order to reduce bundle size i decided to divide it into multiple modules with lazy load. and here is my app-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/public/freelancer-profile/freelancer-profile.module').then(m => m.FreelancerProfileModule)
  },
  {
    canActivate: [LoginGuardService],
    path: 'panel',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/private/private.module').then(m => m.PrivateModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/public/public.module').then(m => m.PublicModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/landing/landing.module').then(m => m.LandingModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/public/logging/logging.module').then(m => m.LoggingModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404',
  }
];
```

i expected landing.module to be loaded only if page path is in its module but here is what happens :
if page path is on logging.module , public.module and landing.module chunks are being downloaded as well.
how can i fix this ?
i was thinking if there was a way to check URLs and download module only if URL matches one of the paths in the module

note: i cant change urls and add prefix to avoid this because pages are indexed through search engines.

Comment: why some paths has empty as same? Does it work?

Comment: this can't work. how would you know which paths are added in the module without loading it? you should rethink your module architecture to map one path prefix to one module.

Comment: some of the path properties in route config are empty. why you do not specify the route for them?

Comment: @ClusterH they have same prefix in their routerchild routes are different
for example i have /home /dashboard in first module and /search and /panel in second module i cant divide them with prefix

Comment: @Clashsoft in production project you cant have added useless prefix to divide chunks  because of seo and loading all landing pages in a single chunk will affect page speed.
i am looking for a way not to load all of landing pages chunk when user visits single page

Comment: @Seyed-Amir-Mehrizi because they dont have the same prefix and i cant specify a route for them. routerchild routes are different in each module.

Comment: why dont you create a HomeModule and a DashboardModule then? If they share components you can create a HomeSharedModule or whatever. Same for the other routes

Comment: @Clashsoft because i would have a large bundle, i wanted to divide them into smaller bundles to increase performance.